# Is the sum of two solvable ideals is nilpotent?

Tags: lie-algebras, ideals

I recently had an exam in Lie algebras course, and there was a true/false question that said:

> The sum of two solvable ideals is nilpotent.

I wrote that this statement is wrong because I know that the sum of two solvable ideals is solvable but solvable is not necessarily nilpotent (a good example is the Lie algebra bn).
Is there any problem in my answer? (Because my teacher said I am wrong and I don't understand why)

Comment: Your answer is correct, but the argument is not complete.

Comment: Do you mean that this statement is true but my explanation is wrong?

Comment: This exam question is not even close to a false naive expectation (such as the more interesting: is the sum of two abelian ideals always abelian?). So a correct answer is just exhibiting a counterexample, and basically as soon as you have an explicit solvable non-nilpotent Lie algebra, you can deduce a counterexample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer is not correct. Yes, the sum of two solvable ideas is solvable and, yes, not all solvable ideals are nilpotent. But you can't deduce from this that the sum of two solvable ideals is sometimes not nilpotent. You seem to be assuming that every solvable ideal is the sum of two solvable ideals. If this was true, then, yes, you would be able to deduce that the sum of two solvable ideals is not always nilpotent.

Comment: (Maybe you wanted to leave it to the OP to figure this out, but:) Well, every solvable ideal $I$ in a given Lie algebra $L$ **can** be written as sum $I + 0$; so if $I$ is solvable but not nilpotent (and OP has an example for this), here we have a counterexample, and he has a correct answer with a correct argument.

Comment: So maybe the better question is the one about a solvable ideal that can be written as a sum of two non-trivial solvable ideals, *than* this sum must be nilpotent?

Comment: But every nontrivial solvable ideal $I$ is sum $I+I$. Also if $I,J$ are Lie algebras, then they're ideals in their direct product. It's just absurd to expect any nilpotency on the sum of two solvable ideals, since nilpotent is, in a sense, "smaller".